# How do I convert a 100 nanosecond Gregorian bigint value to a datetime in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, bigint

So I have a bigint value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since `12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001` in the Gregorian calendar.

An example is `637564207744054251`. I find this and other values like this in PostgreSQL and I need to use Python to convert it to `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` format.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the use of `datetime` and `timedelta`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

duration_ns = 637564207744054251 * 100 # number of 100-nanosecond intervals
duration = timedelta(microseconds=duration_ns / 1000)

start = datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
end = start + duration

end_str = end.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
print(end_str)  # 05/12/21 12:52:54
```